# Getting error after reaching to the last element of array in android

Tags: android, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

After my array reaches the last index, I got an exception saying that the index is out of bounds. What I wanted to do is to go back to the first index. How can I do that?

Here is my work

```
String[] name = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
Button buttonNext;
int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i++;
            nextText(i);
        }
    });
}

private void nextText(int id) {
    Log.i("Name is ", name[id]);
}
```

Comment: Please paste your complete code declaring and using `i` and `array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code to this.

```
 String[] name = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
    Button buttonNext;
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(i < name.length-1)
                   i++;
                else
                   i=0;

                nextText(i);

            }
        });
    }

    private void nextText(int id) {
        Log.i("Name is ", name[id]);
    }
```

Output should be as following.
first time : Name is B
Second time : Name is C
Third time : Name is D
Forth time : Name is A

Comment: same or different error ?

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: try now it will work now. sorry there was an typo

Comment: It's working. Thank you CodingRat :)

Comment: if it is working can you accept the answer and upvote it :)

Comment: hey can you accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
  buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        nextText(i);
     if(i<name.length){
        i++;
         }else{
       i==0;
         }
     });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a check like this

```
buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i++;
            if (i < name.length) nextText(i); //added if condition.
        }
    });
```

Comment: thats not part of question. google out how to implement next/previous in android, you will have n number of posts

Comment: He is asking how to acess first index of array. not about next/previous

Comment: Weird for negative vote. Can i please know the reason for negative vote? @CodingRat default index is already set to zero (which is first index), so as per required condition, index can be set back to 0 anytime, which i do not think is any rocket science to know. I did not wanted to be rude with questioner but instead if guided to get properly implement sample code which can be used directly or with some modification.